# How can I get tradable items of a dota2 player from steam API?

Tags: webapi, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Please give me tested link; I read all API doc but can't found a solution to work..

Also that's items have `img_url`.

---

However I don't know why it doesn't work on this API for me:
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetSchema/v0001/?key=4C58B89D03BDEDD382A4BE91F64B4C0B

Ersor response:

> Not Found
> Method 'GetSchema' not found in interface 'IEconItems_570'